# How to set audio permissions for the desired users

Tags: 18.04, sound, permissions, alsa

I have a pair of speaker devices in a server that I would like to be accessed by all users. These devices are located in /dev/snd... and I have alsa installed... For now they are available only to a user U1 (in the group G1).

After using the commands setfacl and chmod (with sudo) to try to allow the use of these devices by the user U2 (also in group G1), I didn't manage to get a solution.

How can I reset these devices' permissions and how can I set the desired ones?

This user U2 can't also use `alsamixer`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of the problem:

1. Remove all ACLs from the devices:

```
   sudo setfacl -b /dev/snd
   sudo setfacl -b /dev/snd/*
```

2. Then, set permissions for user and group (I set 777 permissions...):

```
   sudo chmod 777 /dev/snd
   sudo chmod 777 /dev/snd/*
```

And my problem was solved! Now, I can use the speakers, the microphone and use `alsamixer` to set the volume in/out!